# jax-rs Link builder is ignoring base uri, want to create absolute link

Tags: hyperlink, jax-rs, hateoas

I am trying to add links to my jax-rs response headers:

```
Link.fromMethod(UserResource.class, "delete")
        .baseUri(getUriInfo().getBaseUri()).rel("delete").build(id);
```

While i see in per debugger and log that `getUriInfo().getBaseUri()` returns the correct uri, the resulting link is only `/1` (for id=1).

Using UriBuilder it is working!

```
URI build = getUriInfo().getBaseUriBuilder().path(UserResource.class, "delete").build(id);
Link.fromUri(build).rel("delete").build();
```

`getUriInfo` just returns uriInfo from base class injected with `@Context`.

So how to get it working with Link (it should work, shouldn't it)?

Comment: I'm currently looking into the same thing, looking at the source for Link (supplied by Resteasy in my case) I see the baseUri is not used anywhere except for the buildRelativized() method, and it only uses it to strip it off and return a relative uri.  It seems like we are out of luck here, although your second snippet using UriBuilder isn't all that ugly.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder();
UriBuilder clone = uriBuilder.clone();
clone.path("xxx");
Link link = Link.fromUriBuilder(clone).rel("self").type("GET").build();
```

cloning because I re use the builder